# How APNS feedback service and GCM Registration ID deletion process are implemented on Appcelerator cloud service (ACS)

Tags: javascript, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, appcelerator-acs

Has anyone implemented APNS feedback service and [Registration ID deletion process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595511/is-there-an-android-gcm-equivalent-to-the-ios-push-notification-feedback-service?answertab=active#tab-top) in Appcelerator cloud service (ACS)?

Currently haven't seen any error response from `notify_token` API.

Ideas?