# server update device not in use

Tags: android, ios, mysql, node.js, push-notification

I am developing a small chat application using node.js for iOS and Android, Now my question is that one user created a account and logged-in using this application from iOS or Android, then the user deleted this application without log-out. How the server knows this device has deleted the application without log-out?. Since, while user again installing this application, the push notification is still arriving without the user log-in.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a feedback service to give you information about failed remote notifications. Basically you listen the messages from feedback.push.apple.com and you flag the devices returned from feedback service. So no further push notifications will be delivered to that device. When user installs your app again you can remove the flag and start delivering the notifications.

For the android part check this question; [Is there an Android GCM equivalent to the iOS Push Notification Feedback Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595511/is-there-an-android-gcm-equivalent-to-the-ios-push-notification-feedback-service)

Comment: you are right, In sometimes this scenario getting failed. For an example: One user have deleted the application, on that time no one sending the any push notification to him. Again, he/she installed the application and not logged-in. Now, How I know, this user newly installed the application.

Comment: You have to create some kind of flag mechanism for this user in the db.

For example set the isDeleted:true when the above feedback mechanisms tell you that user deleted. 

You can send a query from your app to your server everytime user launches the application so you can check the isDeleted flag and set it to false which means he/she reinstalled your app.

Comment: This method I have used already. Once the user installed the application and not opened the application, this time background will not work to hit the server to update that user newly installed the application.